# PHP, Regex and preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract substrings matching given regex expression from the string below:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. `<xy:abc_ref d_id="1234">`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.`<xy:abc_ref d_id="1234">`"

Regex does match it as expected. However, for some reason I can only access the first parsed value. Even though the counter (count($matches)) states there are two results, see the output.

```
$value = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <xy:abc_ref d_id="1234">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <xy:abc_ref d_id="5678">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<xy:abc_ref d_id="1234">';
```

The source:

```
function test($value)
{
    $RegEx = '/<xy:abc_ref ([^>]{0,})>/';       
    $n = preg_match($RegEx,$value,$matches);
    print("Results count: " . count($matches)."<br>");
    print("matches[0]: " . $matches[0]."<br>");
    print("matches[1]: " . $matches[1]."<br>");
    print("matches[2]: " . $matches[2]."<br>");
}
echo test($value);
```

The output:

```
Results count: 2
matches[0]:
matches[1]: d_id="1234"
matches[2]:
```

Thanks, LG

Comment: Sounds like a job for an XML parser, rather than a regex solution. [How to parse and process HTML/XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to get all matches. preg_match will only return the first match. Count will return two because you capture a group.

Answer (score 2):

You must use [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test($value)
{
    $RegEx = '/<xy:abc_ref ([^>]{0,})>/';       
    $n = preg_match_all($RegEx,$value,$matches);
    print("Results count: " . count($matches[1])."<br>");
    print("matches[0]: " . $matches[1][0]."<br>");
    print("matches[1]: " . $matches[1][1]."<br>");
    print("matches[2]: " . $matches[1][2]."<br>");
}
```